# Windows Defender keep blocking my application that project for college homework

Tags: c#, windows, false-positive, windows-defender

Im working on application for my college homework. It will show a lot of windows info to user. But windows defender dont let me run the program without add exe on exclusions. Looks like a generic blocking. I dont want present that for my entire class... there something i have to do for windows defender stop flagging like this.

im coding in VS 2022 in c#[image]

i will appreciate a lot any help or orientation

Comment: As per the message, you should contact your IT help desk.

Comment: Defender does this this on a lot of unknown .exe files that are not popular. Tweak the settings or use a different AV product.